# What is the difference between these two statements?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have these two statements :

```
printf("%u",a+1);
```

and

```
printf("%u",(int *)a+1);
```

Actually I was working on this code when I came across this confusion.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a[2][2]={1,2,3,4};
  int i,j;
  int *p[] = { (int*)a, (int*)a+1, (int*)a+2 };
  for(i=0; i<2; i++){
    for(j=0; j<2; j++){
      printf("%d %d %d %d",* (*(p+i)+j), *(*(j+p)+i), *(*(i+p)+j), *(*(p+j)+i));
    }
  }
  return 0; 
}

Output:

1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
```

In order to understand the output of the above program I came to know that the difference that's making this output can be solved if I know the difference between above two statements.

My current understanding:
`(a+1)` will give me the address of 2nd element of array. In this case a 2-d array can be visualized as 2 1-d arrays, each with 2 elements.  So `(a+1)` will give me the address of `a[1][0]`, but then why is `(int *)a+1` giving me the address of `a[0][1]`?

Please explain the difference and the output of the program.

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing like `printf("%u",a+1)` appears in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiom `(int*)a+1` is interpreted as `((int*)a) + 1)`.  That is, the cast takes precedence over the addition.  So this evaluates to `(int*) a)`, which is the address of the array as ptr-to-int, offset by 1, which returns the second element in the array (`2`).

Two critical rules of programming:

**Rule 1:** When you *write* code, make the layout reflect the functionality.
**Rule 2:** When you *read* code, read the functionality, not the layout.  (Corollary: debug the *code*, not the *comments*.)

Conceptually, when you declare

```
int a[2][2]={1,2,3,4};
```

you envision a 2 dimensional array like this:

```
  1 2
  3 4
```

But C actually stores the data in a contiguous block of memory, like this:

```
  1 2 3 4
```

It "remembers" that the data represents a 2×2 array when it calculates the indices. But when you cast `a` from its original type to `int *`, you're telling the compiler to forget about its original declaration, effectively losing its 2-dimensionality and becoming a simple vector of `int`s.

Here's how to understand the declaration of `p`:

```
int *p[] = { (int*) a,  (int*) a+1,     (int*) a+2 };     // As written
int *p[] = { (int*) a,  ((int*) a) + 1, ((int*) a) + 2 }; // As interpreted
int *p[] = { &a[0][0],  &a[0][1],       &a[1][0] };       // Resulting values
```

From this, you can see that `p` is a one-dimensional array of vectors:

```
p[0] = { 1, 2, 3 }
p[1] = { 2, 3 }
p[2] = { 3 }
```

If you recognize that `(p+i) == (i+p)`, then the last two items are the same as the first two in the line

```
printf("%d %d %d %d\n",* (*(p+i)+j), *(*(j+p)+i), *(*(i+p)+j), *(*(p+j)+i));
```

which is equivalent to this:

```
printf("%d %d %d %d\n", p[i+j], p[j+i], p[i+j], p[j+i]);
```

---

It's interesting to note that, since the following are all equivalent:

```
a[i]
*(a+i)
*(i+a)
```

then it's perfectly legal to write `i[a]` to represent the same value.  In other words, the compiler allows you to write

```
printf("%d %d %d %d\n", p[i], i[p], p[1], 1[p]);
```

Of course, your tech lead had better *not* allow you to write that.  If you write that in my group, you're fired.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks I got it now.The key concept is cast takes precedence over addition.

Answer (score 2):

None, both produce undefined behavior. The correct format to print a pointer value is `%p`. Cast your pointer to `void*` when sending it to `printf`.

Comment: He's never printing pointer values; they're all dereferenced twice.

Comment: @Adam, he never said what the values `a` in the `printf` represent. The variable `a` that is declared in his code is an array. Then he *is* printing a pointer value in the second case, since he is casting whatever `a+1` represents to `int*`.

Comment: Ah - you were referring to the initial part of the question; I was referring to the actual code.  No wonder we were confused.  Before one can debug the problem, one must first debug the person asking it.  :-)

Comment: @Adam, say I was referring to *the question* he asked, which is in the title.

Comment: Right--the title asks a specific question, continued briefly in the text, and then the example elaborates on something different entirely.    I may need to adjust the range of my short-term memory.

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional C arrays behave like single-dimensional arrays laid out next to each other.  So if you cast `a` (normally `(int **)`) to `(int *)` you get the same thing you would get from `a[0]`.  Thus `(int *) a + 1` is `&a[0][1]`.  Otherwise your understanding is correct, which is why `a + 1` gets you `&a[1][0]`.

(This behavior is specified by the standard; but that does not make it good programming practice.)

Comment: `int[M][N]` is *not* `int**`, and in fact behaves quite differently.

Comment: I'm not getting it.How can (int *)a gives me same thing as a[0] ? Can you please explain it in a bit detail ?